# Clipboard.GetText() not working on windows server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, clipboard, windows-server-2008-r2

I've got a problem with my asp.net program. I'm trying to read text from the the Clipboard, which works perfectly with this code:

```
protected void btn_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ClipboardText = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText();
    ClipboardText = ClipboardText.Replace("\r\n", " ");
    string[] ImportText = ClipboardText.Split();
    int RowIndex = 0;
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();
    Gridview_To_Dataset(gv_CreateAgent, true, false, true);

    foreach (string NtAccount in ImportText)
    {
        try
        {
            if (NtAccount != "")
            {
                int pos = NtAccount.IndexOf("_");
                if (pos > 0)
                {
                    ((TextBox)gv_CreateAgent.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("crea_NTaccount")).Text = NtAccount.Substring(0, pos).ToLower();
                    ((DropDownList)gv_CreateAgent.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("crea_ddlType")).SelectedItem.Text = NtAccount.Substring(pos).Trim().ToLower();
                    dtTemp = Gridview_To_Dataset(gv_CreateAgent, false, false, false);
                    ReadDirex(dtTemp, RowIndex);
                    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ((TextBox)gv_CreateAgent.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("crea_NTaccount")).Text = NtAccount.Trim().ToLower();
                    ((DropDownList)gv_CreateAgent.Rows[RowIndex].FindControl("crea_ddlType")).SelectedItem.Text = " ";
                    dtTemp = Gridview_To_Dataset(gv_CreateAgent, false, false, false);
                    ReadDirex(dtTemp, RowIndex);
                    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            this.lbl_falschernt.Visible = true;
            this.lbl_falschernt.Text = "Fehler beim Einlesen : Es dürfen nur NT-Accounts eingelesen werden!";
        }
    }
}
```

And in asp.net i added this:

```
AspCompat="true" %>
```

Like i said, on my local computer this works perfectly. However on my windows server 2008 R2 it doesn't work at all. I don't get an error but nothing happens.

I tried a few things like `[STAThread]`, which doesn't make any sense cause off

```
AspCompat="true"
```

So what could be the problem?
I'm thankful about any advice!

Comment: Even if it did work, it would be getting the contents of the clipboard for the user account under which the *service* is running. This is very likely empty. If you want the contents of the clipboard for the user who is using their browser to access your site, you'll be looking for some javascript, not `ClipBoard.GetText`. Hint: If you find yourself adding `System.Windows.Forms` into an asp.net application, you're very likely going off the rails. It "works" on your machine when it's both the server *and* the browser.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have the feeling you're right. My thought was to add a TextBox so you could CTRL + V into the TextBox and read it from there out. Not the best solution but should work.